# Upgrading to rails 3.2.3.rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right, the code below should explain everything. This is taken from ubuntu's console. As you can see I can't seem to update my rails version. Yes, I have the same problem after preceding with 'sudo' ... Thanks for the help !

```
funkdified@funkdified-laptop:~/railsprojects/goodsounds$ gem install rails -v 3.2.3.rc1
Successfully installed rails-3.2.3.rc1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.3.rc1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.3.rc1...
funkdified@funkdified-laptop:~/railsprojects/goodsounds$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.2
```

UPDATE: I thought somehow my RVM environment might be useful somehow:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p125-HEAD@rails323:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux funkdified-laptop 2.6.32-37-386 #81-Ubuntu SMP Sat Dec 3 00:07:25 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.11.3 () by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"
    updated:      "41 minutes 4 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.3p125"
    date:         "2012-02-16"
    platform:     "i686-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2012-02-16 revision 34643"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [i686-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-HEAD@rails323"
    ruby:         "/home/funkdified/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125-HEAD"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/funkdified/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125-HEAD/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/funkdified/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125-HEAD/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/funkdified/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125-HEAD/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-HEAD@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-HEAD@rails323/bin:/home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-HEAD@global/bin:/home/funkdified/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125-HEAD/bin:/home/funkdified/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-HEAD@rails323"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-HEAD@rails323:/home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-HEAD@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/funkdified/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125-HEAD"
    IRBRC:        "/home/funkdified/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125-HEAD/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       "rails323"
```

Comment: gem which rails link the 3.2.3.rc1 gem ?

Comment: funkdified@funkdified-laptop:~/railsprojects/goodsounds$ gem which rails
/home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-HEAD@rails323/gems/railties-3.2.3.rc1/lib/rails.rb

Comment: Have you a Gemfile in the directory you launch the rails command ?

Comment: Shingara, I'm sorry I don't know what you mean. Can you please explain? Thank you.

Comment: What is the output from `ruby -v`?  You have RVM installed in your home directory (which is fine).  As a result though you should not ever use sudo when running gem, rails, etc. commands.

Comment: funkdified@funkdified-laptop:~/railsprojects/goodsounds$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [i686-linux]

Comment: in the directory where you launch your rails command. if there are a Gemfile ( bundler configuration ) and you have some script to launch `bundler exec` in front of your script so it's normal to have rails 3.2.2 allways activate if you have rails 3.2.2 in your Gemfile not 3.2.3.rc1

Comment: Every rails project has its own Gemfile.  So there should be one in the goodsounds directory.  As shingara says, make sure the rails version specified in that file is the one you want to use.  Near the top it should say `gem 'rails', '3.2.3.rc1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed a new version of the `rails` gem but this doesn't mean your application will use it.

Your rails application contains a `Gemfile.lock` with all the gem's versions, if you want your application use the newer `rails`:

1. update your `Gemfile` with the new rails gem version
2. run `gem update rails`.

Same answer - Longer edition:

1. The `Gemfile` is a file in your application with the application dependencies. For each gem you can specify the version you need (e.g. "1.2.1" or ">= 3.0.0" or "~> 3.0.0" which means greater or equal to 3.0.0 but lesser than 3.1.0)
2. Since different gem version behave in a different way to avoid problems your application gems versions are fixed and your application know which version of each gem to use to work without problem. This is made storing these information in the `Gemfile.lock` file
3. Since the gem versions for your application are "locked", if you want to upgrade a gem to a newer version you need to run `bundle update gemname`, this will upgrade/install (if needed) the gem and update the `Gemfile.lock` accordingly.
4. **NOTE**: the gems are updated in the respect of your Gemfile so if you run `bundle update rails` but your application `Gemfile` says your application needs exactly rails 3.2.1 your application will still use this version, you need to edit your Gemfile and then run `bundle update rails`